# Undefined control sequence error for sum expression in equation

Tags: math-mode

The below sum expression inside the equation throws an undefined control sequence error.

```
\begin{equation}
    \left\|x\left[t\right]-\textbf{1} F(X)\right\|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lambda_i^2t     \lvert x \left[ 0 \right] \rvert^2
\end{equation}
```

Error:

Undefined control sequence.

```
|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lambda_i^2t \lvert 
                                        x \left[ 0 \right] \rvert^2
```

My guess is I am doing something wrong with the `\lvert` or `\lambda`. Don't know exactly. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue will be very helpful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `\usepackage{amsmath}`.  The MWE below produces:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left\|x\left[t\right]-\textbf{1} F(X)\right\|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lambda_i^2t     \lvert x \left[ 0 \right] \rvert^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, after including amsmath package, that problem is resolved but a new message is coming up "Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures (amsmath)   trying to recover with `aligned'." Any idea on why this is happening will be helpful.

Comment: @SomnathChakrabarti: Check whether you've inadvertently created nested `equation` environments.

Comment: As I suggested in the comments, please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass`.